# jQuery callback functions make animations run sequentially

Tags: jquery, fadeout, jquery-callback

My problem is:

Because callback function will be called once the fadeOut is complete, can I put the callback function right after (outside) the fadeOut function ?

Here is the situation:

I try to build a picture rotator with jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn functions. The idea is to put three pictures in three layers by setting different CSS z-index values. Then use setInterval to change their locations repeatedly.

But I found the fade effect disappears when I wrote

`curr.fadeOut(1000);`

`next.removeClass("previous").addClass("current");`

`curr.removeClass("current").fadeIn();`

And the code is [JSFIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/QqmTV/1/);

If I put the last two lines into the fadeOut, in other words, treat them as a callback function, the fade effect works.

I wrote the right code here:

`curr.fadeOut(1000, function(){`

`next.removeClass("previous").addClass("current");`

`curr.removeClass("current").fadeIn();`

`});`

And the code is [JSFIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxftY/1/)

Comment: It is about the execution order of jQuery functions. Try the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8sqUd/ . If we don't use callback function, the code will be executed parallelly. Otherwise, the code will be executed in sequence.

Comment: I also notice that for the same object, the animations will be executed sequentially, but for different objects, they will be triggered at the same time.